# async parallel modbus-serial node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, modbus

I try with this code but can't get the value, anyone can help me? sorry because I'm a newbie in NodeJS. I don't understand why the code can't return the value.

```
const ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial");

var client = new ModbusRTU();

client.connectRTUBuffered("COM3", { baudRate: 9600 });

var async = require("async");

setInterval(function(callback) {

async.parallel({

        async_modbus_1_1: function(clbk) {

            client.writeFC3(1, 4103, 2, function(err, data) {

                console.log(data);

            });

        },

        async_modbus_1_2: function(clbk) {

            client.writeFC3(1, 4106, 2, function(err, data) {

                console.log(data);

            });

        },

        async_modbus_2_1: function(clbk) {

            client.writeFC3(3, 4103, 2, function(err, data) {

                console.log(data);

            });

        },

        async_modbus_2_2: function(clbk) {

            client.writeFC3(3, 4106, 2, function(err, data) {

                console.log(data);

            });

        }
    },
    function(error, result) {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        if (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }

    });

}, 1000);
```

I try to connect into modbus slave with that code, when i try to running the I don't get value return from the modbus slave, and in the modbus slave I just get this value without Tx value

000781-Rx:01 03 10 07 00 02 71 0A 01 03 10 0A 00 02 E0 C9 03 03 10 07 00 02 70 E8 03 03 10 0A 00 02 E1 2B

[Image for respon from modbus slave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML90V.png)

Comment: what is the problem and what you try to do at where error occur. please provide more detail according to my questions

Comment: I try to connect into modbus slave with that code, when i try to running the I don't get value return from the modbus slave, and in the modbus slave I just get this value without Tx value => 
000781-Rx:01 03 10 07 00 02 71 0A 01 03 10 0A 00 02 E0 C9 03 03 10 07 00 02 70 E8 03 03 10 0A 00 02 E1 2B

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you still need help, but this issue is caused due to attempting to send commands in parallel. Since you are on a Modbus serial communication, you must wait to receive a response before sending another command. You cannot use Async since it will send commands in parallel over a serial connection.